# Hide toolbar on top of iPhone keyboard

Tags: javascript, jquery, iphone, keyboard, cordova

Is there any way in JavaScript or HTML to hide the toolbar from iPhone keyboard.
I only have one form input and I don't want the user to see the next, previous or done.

I am using PhoneGap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. If you log into the Apple Dev Forums (under Web Technologies), an Apple Evangelist will tell you the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

**Well yes, it can be done**. It has been discussed in several StackOverflow questions around. [Here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5273073/phonegap-iphone-apps-touch-pad-contains-additional-bar/13715130#13715130) of how it can be done

It might not be the prettiest solusion you'll ever see but it sure works and that's what matters.